# Distribution of correlation coefficients for uniform random variables

Tags: correlation, references, uniform-distribution

Let $n>1$, let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[-\frac12,\frac12]$, and consider the sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}$ of independent copies of $X$.

R implements `pearson`, `kendall` and `spearman` measures of correlation in its function `cor`. So for each of these methods, if I compute

```
cor(X[1:n], X[2:(n+1)], method=...)
```

is there a known distribution for the resulting correlation coefficient? The `pearson` coefficient seems to be almost normally distributed, but for $n=10$ and method `spearman` it seems to be noticeably non-normal. Also, both `kendall` and `spearman` are discrete.

I'm trying to figure out if in a long sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_{m(n+1)}$ of $m$ windows of size $n$, each window's consecutive random variables are independent. So I calculate the correlation coefficient for each window, and want to know its distribution under the hypothesis that they are all independent uniformly distributed as above.

Are these distributions known? If not, are there any good approximations?

Comment: Just try simulations.